# CNF conversion problem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I don't understand how $(a\lor b\lor \lnot c) \land c = (a\lor b) \land c$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(a\lor b\lor \lnot c) \land c \overset{(Distribution)}{=}$$

$$(a\land c) \lor (b \land c) \lor (\lnot c \land c)  \overset{(Complement)}{=}$$

$$(a\land c) \lor (b \land c) \lor \bot \overset{ (Identity)}{=}$$

$$(a\land c) \lor (b \land c)  \overset{ (Distribution)}{=}$$

$$(a\lor b) \land c$$

This is such a common pattern, that there is a special equivalence principle for it:

**Reduction**

$a \land (\neg a \lor b) = a \land b$

and its dual: $a \lor (\neg a \land b) = a \lor b$

Comment: The notation you use is confusing and is an abuse of notation.  For example, we have that $(a \lor b\lor \lnot c) \land c \equiv (a\land c)\lor b\land c) \lor (\lnot c \land c) \tag{by distribution}$  which is equivalent to line three by reason of .... which is equivalent to line four by reason of .....

Answer (score 0):

Note that: $$(a \lor b \lor \neg c) \land c = (a \land c) \lor ( b \land c) \lor ( \neg c \land c) =  (a \land c) \lor ( b \land c) = (a \lor b) \land c$$

The transition from the second to the third step is becuase $(\neg c \land c)$ is the identity with which $$\text{ expression } \lor \text{ identity } = \text{ expression }$$